# Importing Live contacs does not import all contacts

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-identity, live-sdk

When trying to import contacts from window live api it only gives me contacts i created in outlook.com, ones that is imported from yahoo to outlook.com it does not come back with this request below.

```
string queryParm = String.Format("access_token={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(accessToken));
            string url = "https://apis.live.net/v5.0/me/contacts?" + queryParm;
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string tmp = reader.ReadToEnd();
            Debug.WriteLine(tmp);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason why it doesn't import your yahoo contact are because in outlook.com it is not outlook contact but a copy of your yahoo contact.

In Outlook.com it look like in your contact, but it's only a share.
Maybe it's a point to look!